# How to log in using Azure Active Directory

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, azure-active-directory

I am using: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client and https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure to allow users to register/login using their MS accounts.

I have the first bit working: Users click the login with MS button. Request is then sent and received for auth code. Request is then sent and received for token.

I then create a new user in my application and log them in.

What should happen the second time they visit my application? Should they click the button again and somehow be logged in using the token?

Comment: One thing I've seen many apps to is attempt to get token silently when the user lands on the page. If it succeeds, you send the user into the authenticated UX; otherwise, you drop them on the screen with the login button.  This is an alternative to always forcing them to hit the login button.

Answer (score 0):

If they still have an active session cookie, they probably won't need to re-authenticate. But it depends. If you need a new access token and can't use a refresh token to do so, you will need them to do the authentication again.

To re-authenticate, they will click the button and go through same flow.

The important thing that you need to do on your app's side is:

1. User logged in
2. Get the object identifier claim value from the `oid` claim
3. Check with the object id if the user exists already
4. If they don't, create the data for them

The `oid` claim will be in the ID token that you can ask for when authenticating, and you also get it when you exchange the authorization code for an access token.

Documentation on claims in ID tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#idtokens

Comment: Small clarification to this answer. If they have a valid session cookie and have consented for the resource they want an access token for, they can silently get an access token for the new resource.

Comment: Yes, using a refresh token in the back end. Or did you mean some other way? :)

Comment: I was referring to another way.  If the client app has a valid persistent session cookie, it can use ADAL (or implement it themselves of course) to pop a hidden i-frame and get a new access token.  If you're interested in more detail, checkout the [ADAL.js acquireToken()](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L663).

Comment: Clarification: This is referring to browser-only applications that call APIs (sometimes called Single Page Apps).

Comment: Yes, that is true. OP did not specify whether they had a SPA though.